# events not working after replacing an element with clone element

Tags: javascript, events, clone

I replaced a div with the clone of another div, now I want to use the same button click events in the cloned div but the events are not working in the replaced div when I am using clone(true), any suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divClone = $("#col2").clone(true);
  $("#bt1").click(function () {
        $("#col2").appendTo("#col1");
        $('#col3').load("data1.html");
    });
 $(document).on('click', '.clo', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#col3").replaceWith(divClone.clone(true));
    });
});
```

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode: "Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (inline) listeners. It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element properties (e.g., node.onclick = someFunction). Additionally, for a <canvas> element, the painted image is not copied."

What's the larger picture of what you're trying to achieve? There has to be a better (working!) way.

Comment: There are 3 columns in my bootstrap page(col1,col2,col3). 
On first loading of the page only col2 has data along with buttons.
On clicking of a particular button(bt1), respective data(data1) should be loaded in col3 and content 
of col2 should move to col1.
Now there is a close button in data1 page, on pressing of that button, data1 should become hidden and col3
should be replaced with original col2 data. Again when bt1 is clicked above steps should be repeated.
Now issue is when bt1 is clicked after the col3 was replaced, nothing is happening.